# switch user to sudo su root and connect the fttp get the file in local machine and unzip

Tags: linux, bash

Hi automating some task to change the user from local  to sudo su root and connect to ftp server and get the .gz file from ftp to local machine gunzip that file and restore into PostgreSQL BD, but i'm not able to change the user

## some sample script that i used in script

1.spawn sudo -s <

expect "password for username:"

send -- "production123\r"

expect eof

## error:-

-bash: ./dbbackup.sh: /usr/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied

2. sudo -kSs << EOF

production123

whoami

echo "Not a good idea to have a password encoded in plain text"

EOF

## error :its also not switching the user

3.sudo -s <

expect "password for username:"

send -- "production123\r"

expect eof

## error

[production@nsuat crons]$ ./dbbackup.sh
./dbbackup.sh: line 1: EOF: No such file or directory
./dbbackup.sh: line 3: expect: command not found
./dbbackup.sh: line 5: send: command not found
./dbbackup.sh: line 7: expect: command not found
[production@nsuat crons]$

Comment: Could you please try to edit your question so that it is a bit more understandable? I mean, your question seems to boil down to how to be able to use `sudo` from a script, but there's plenty of other stuff also which blurs the context...

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit hard to understand. But, if I may, I could offer an alternative approach. Make a specific user that runs the backup, and give it passwordless sudo rights. Now set up the cron job (or whatnot you use) to run as that user, and have the backup script elevate (sudo) it's rights where needed.

Alternatively, depending on how you Postgres is set up, you could just have the postgres user be the one running the restore.

Comment: Hi @Anders Olsson, after DBbackup server keep the .gz file with owner/group root   on ftp server, i have a local machine with owner/group production,to take the backup and restore in Postgres we use local server when i open putty i give password production123 and then i changes to super user sudo su root which ask for password so while doing by script i cant able to changes the user .i use above script but its not working, if i'm doing same task with owner production while using restore command su postgres -c "psql -d Dhruva-test -f  daily-backup-16-12"  its ask for password

Comment: Are you login in as a user _production_ to through SSH, then using su to _root_, then using su again to user _postgres_? Are there any intermediate steps there, or? You can use _sudo_ as any user you want, with the *-u* flag.

Comment: Hi @Anders Olsson Ya ,after login to SSH default in production then i changed to sudo su root to get the .gz file from FTP and Then i do gunzip after gunzip i restore it into DB. but i'm trying to do  by script but i'm not able to changes the user.

Comment: So, if you had [passwordless sudo](http://serverfault.com/a/160587/187123) set up for the user, you could simply use _sudo_ for the commands which need root access, and _sudo -u postgres_ for the restore command. Please tell me if this is not an option, and you only want help with expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this; it works for me:

```
echo "[Password]" | su [UserName] -c [Command/Script to be executed]
```